# Running pubsub/kafka-connector from command line java

Tags: cloud, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub, apache-kafka-connect

As per the documentation under https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/pubsub/tree/master/kafka-connector

Built the jar target/cps-kafka-connector.jar

While running on command line as java -jar cps-kafka-connector.jar

It says no main manifest attribute, in cps-kafka-connector.jar

Do I need to create a separate main class in order to run it? Anyone has executed kafka-connector for Kafka to cloud pub?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the "Pre-Running Steps" and the "Running a Connector" steps on the [documentation page you linked to](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/pubsub/tree/master/kafka-connector). You cannot run the jar directly from the command line. You have to configure [Kafka Connect](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#connect) to use the Cloud Pub/Sub connector, ensure cps-kafka-connector.jar is in your classpath, and then run Kafka Connect. [Sample configs](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/pubsub/tree/master/kafka-connector/config) (where you need to swap in your project and topics) are provided. With these configurations, Kafka Connect will send messages from Kafka to Cloud Pub/Sub (or vice versa, depending on which configuration is used).